# Column Selection In Generic Repository Class

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a Generic Repository class like below:

[image]

I have many methods in this class and I would like all classes to have an extra parameter that will take `Func<T, T>` or sth else (but same for all) that will *be for selection of columns* since most of the time I will not be pulling all the columns when querying.

I would like to know how can I do this more efficiently instead of adding one more parameter in all methods or creating overloads for each method?

Comment: How do you imagine that? Like, when you return only a subset of columns from `GetAll`, what would the return type be?

Comment: @GertArnold This is my `GetAll` function `public List<T> GetAll(Func<T, T> selector = null){IQueryable<T> query = dbset;if (selector != null)query = query.Select(selector).AsQueryable();return query.ToList();}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have one generic parameter for the entity and one for the projected type:

```
List<TResult> Get<TEntity, TResult>(Expr<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector)
```

Consider just exposing a queryable:

```
IQueryable<T> Query<T>() { return _context.GetTable<T>(); }
```

This makes all of these issues go away. Your `Get*` methods add no value. They just restrict the possible query patterns.

Comment: +1 ... or even remove this useless generic repository wrapper.

Comment: @usr So, how do I use your solution in conjunction with something else I might need to pass like an `order` or `where` clause?

Comment: @GertArnold If I remove the generic repository class then how will it contain the Add, Update and Delete methods for me to use?

Comment: @Md.lbrahim `from e in repo.Get<MyEntity>() ...`. Do any query you like. You are no longer restricted.

Comment: @usr Cannot get `GetTable` method on my 'DataContext' ?

Comment: @usr I like your idea of exposing a queryable and I can use it like `_uow.Services.Query().Where(s => s.Status == true).Select(Name => Name.Name).ToList()` but I am still unclear about your previous suggestion.

Comment: What was my *previous* suggestion? You can use this queryable any way you like. It will behave exactly as if you had written `_context.GetTable<T>()`.

Comment: @usr I meant this `List<TResult> Get<TEntity, TResult>(Expr<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector)` I cannot get this to work. For now, I can work with returning `IQueryable<T>` but I will still prefer sending the the linq query to the repo and execute there instead of working it from client code. Hope I was clear.

Comment: @usr I am not getting how you are suggesting me to use your way. I mean I get I can do this which would replace most Get* queries:

`public List<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = null, Func<T, T> selector = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbset;

            if (where != null)
                query = query.Where(where);

            if (selector != null)
                query = query.Select(selector).AsQueryable();

            return query.ToList();
        }`